# MySQL SELECT this year vs thist time last year

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I am trying to make some statistics for a project. I am trying to compare data pr month from this year to the same month from last year.

best I have right now is this

```
SELECT COUNT(tappe_id) FROM tappesesjon WHERE YEAR(tappedato) = YEAR(CURDATE()) GROUP BY MONTH(tappedato) DESC;
SELECT COUNT(tappe_id) FROM tappesesjon WHERE YEAR(tappedato) = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) GROUP BY MONTH(tappedato) DESC;
```

but it doesnt really do the trick

EDIT:
The first query gives me the ammount of "sessions" during each month this year, and the second one gives me the same for last year. What I want is a way to for eksample see how many more sessions there was january of this year than january of last year. 
I hope this sheds some light on my issue

EDIT2:
`tappe_id   tappedato     person_nr
 1         2016-04-22     1231231231
 2         2017-04-22     1231231231
 3         2017-05-01     1231231231
 4         2016-05-01     1231231231
 5         2017-04-23     1231231231
 6         2016-05-01     1231231231
 7         2017-07-12     1231231231
 8         2016-07-07     1231231231
 9         2017-08-12     1231231231
 10        2016-07-07     1231231231`

Comment: You will need to do a better job of explaining what exactly isn't doing the trick.  Show us what this delivers and what you expect to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of your question is that you want to know the difference between number of sessions in curr year and past year, per month.

Here is my solution for above mentioned problem,

```
SELECT COUNT(a.tappe_id) - COUNT(b.tappe_id)
FROM tappesesjon a, tappesesjon b
WHERE  YEAR(a.tappedato) = YEAR(CURDATE())
    AND a.tappedato = DATE_ADD(b.tappedato, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY MONTH(a.tappedato);
```

Comment: somehow when I tried to use that query, it returned zero (yes i correced currdate to curdate)

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of data in your table.

Comment: tappe_id   tappedato                  person_nr
1               2016-04-22               1231231231
2               2017-04-22               1231231231
3               2017-05-01               1231231231
4               2016-05-01               1231231231
5               2017-04-23               1231231231
6               2016-05-01               1231231231
7               2017-07-12               1231231231
8               2016-07-07               1231231231
9               2017-08-12               1231231231
10             2016-07-07               1231231231

Comment: Hey, I have updated my answer. This should work well.

Comment: Actual problem was that you wanted to get the difference between counts where the difference between "dates" was 1 year; and not the same month previous year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MONTH(tappeddato),
       SUM(YEAR(tappedato) = YEAR(CURDATE())) as cnt_current,
       SUM(YEAR(tappedato) = YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1) as cnt_lastyera,
FROM tappesesjon
WHERE YEAR(tappedato) IN (YEAR(CURDATE()), YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1)
GROUP BY MONTH(tappedato) DESC;
```

Comment: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as cnt_current, SUM(YEAR(tappedato) = YEAR(CURDATE() - 1) as cnt_lastyera' at line 2"

cant find what is wrong here. I have only been learning SQL for a few months